# How to change root namespace for Symfony 4 maker bundle?

Tags: symfony4

I'm trying to change the default App namespace to AppBundle (the project uses S4, but the directory structure is still 3.4, currently) for Symfony 4 MakerBundle as instructed here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html#configuration.  It states I need to create a file in config/packages/dev/maker.yaml, but it does not specify what that is relative to?  I've tried /app/config/packages/dev/maker.yaml, /config/packages/dev/maker.yaml, /src/AppBundle/Resources/config/packages/dev/maker.yaml, but it seems to just ignore any of those and try to create it in App.  I've followed the format of the documentation:

```
# config/packages/dev/maker.yaml
# create this file if you need to configure anything
maker:
    # tell MakerBundle that all of your classes lives in an
    # Acme namespace, instead of the default App
    # (e.g. Acme\Entity\Article, Acme\Command\MyCommand, etc)
    root_namespace: 'AppBundle'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear the cache after you've created the configuration.

Comment: Thanks. This was the cause of my issue on Symfony *6*.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, I am using 3.4 and found you have to place the maker config in

> app/config/config_dev.yml

for it to work. I also had to modify my doctrine.yml orm mapping for the entity manager like so:

```
mappings:
    AppBundle:
        is_bundle: false
        type: annotation
        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/AppBundle/Entity'
        prefix: 'AppBundle\Entity'
        alias: AppBundle
```